# Flutter Firebase Getting SubCollection Datas of Specific Multiple Documents

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

This my Firebase Documents Form;

[image: Users Collection]

[image: Users Posts]

I have Users collection and I have users in Users collection with different documentIDs.

Each user has 2 value (name and documentID) and has Posts collection.

There are also post documents with a name value in the Posts collection.

I am looking for a data getting of multiple documents method suitable for this database form, as it is an option to follow a user in the application and see the posts of the user they are following.

If we give an example over this database;

For example, I am trying to get Posts data of users "9L0kdExw5Q1HvUnrXrSE", "rdzfk7U41IQCfxuv1Gp0".

How can I do that.

I tried many different methods but none worked. I've been struggling with this for days.

There has to be a simple method for this, how do those who make social media applications with Flutter do it.

I hope it was self explanatory and has a solution.

Comment: I solved my problem, you can check it from this link; [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70407597/flutter-firebase-merge-streams-list-with-combinelateststream-and-display-on-stre/70433919#70433919](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70407597/flutter-firebase-merge-streams-list-with-combinelateststream-and-display-on-stre)

Answer (score 0):

first, i would suggest to add the **user id** of the 'author' in the post document.

second, use **collectionGroup** queries (more of it [here](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/06/understanding-collection-group-queries.html)). you can then use an "in" clause for the query (see [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_not-in_and_array-contains-any))

note however, that "in" clause only allows up to 10 comparison values.

Comment: When I first made the application, I used the method you said, then when I got the error that the whereIN query can only query 10 values, I had to find a different solution.

Comment: Do you have any other suggestions or how to make a whereIN query without limits?

Comment: Hi @Rkdio, please check this [blog](https://flutter-developer.medium.com/flutter-avoid-wherein-10-limit-in-firestore-adafe8977601) and see if it helps.

Comment: It recommends me to query multiple times, then merge it locally in my application, but he did not give an example for this, and I did not understand how to do it.

Comment: I solved my problem and I uploaded the answer, if anyone is curious, you can take a look.